# miktex total crash

Tags: miktex

After Sunday June 28 massive update, miktex started working bad namely both latex and pdflatex working in total crash way (no interaction at all, with no hint of mistake). Today, I tried to reinstall miktex twice and it came from bad to worse with absolute total disfunctionality. Any latex run ends with

```
Sorry, but C:\PROGRA~1\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  C:\Users\vov\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\latex.log
OxEdit: module reports errors!!! 

latex.log says (47mm3.tex is the file, but the crash happens with any file). Aditionally, after a compulsory update upon the installation, the consone update also crashes, returning "Configuration error: no conversion from undefined configuration value to string."

2020-06-30 08:17:16,444+0300 INFO  latex - this process (3164) started by 'OxEdit' with command line: C:\PROGRA~1\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe 47mm3
2020-06-30 08:17:16,444+0300 INFO  latex - allowing known shell commands
2020-06-30 08:17:16,444+0300 INFO  latex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 FATAL latex.core - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 FATAL latex.core - Data: 
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 FATAL latex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp:77
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 FATAL latex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 FATAL latex - Info: 
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 FATAL latex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 FATAL latex - Line: 77
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 INFO  latex - this process (3164) finishes with exit code 1
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 WARN  miktex.core - still open: 47mm3.tex
2020-06-30 08:17:16,629+0300 WARN  miktex.core - still open: 47mm3.log
```

Any remedy? I have just started to install texlive, looking to take a full day or more, but I got accustomed to miktex ...

Comment: Go to the MiKTeX issue tracker. The bug has been reported and there you can find or ask for advice how to repair MiKTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I couldn't find any open or recently closed issue related to this 'no conversion from undefined configuration value to string' error in MiKTeX console. I didn't yet dare to run pdflatex.exe, but guess that miktex-console.exe might be causing another issue not directly related to pdflatex.exe/latex.exe? Started a new issue [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/571).

Comment: Have you tried to run `latex` at the command-line prompt? For example: `pdflatex.exe 47mm3`

Comment: over a simple file like \documentclass{article}\begin{document}XXX\end{document}

Comment: over a simple file like \documentclass{article}\begin{document}XXX\end{document} pdflatex works, But 1) if I add something problematic like an undefined macro like \xxx - it crashes w/o any pdf created and w/o any attempt to discuss a fix, and 2) updates are disabled, so requested packages cannot be loaded and it crashes at first stop of any kind. So miktex is disfunctional now on my desktop. I was fortunate not to update miktex on my laptop.

Comment: According to the ticket you opened, this has been fixed. Can you confirm this?